# How to change timeout value of the connect API?

Tags: android, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

We are getting the following errors in high volume from our Android and iPhone applications, especially UNRESPONSIVE_HOST and then REQUEST_TIMEOUT. And this seems to happen at the `WL.Client.connect()` initialization routine.

It is possible that the user may have a volatile Internet or Wifi connection.  That is possible.  But it seems there is something more systemic. What typically causes unresponsive host error? Why is a timeout different than a unresponsive host? What are the default timeouts? 10 seconds? Before those errors are thrown?  Is there a way to change the timeout.

> REQUEST_TIMEOUT / UNRESPONSIVE_HOST …
>
> Response Error : The request timed out.
>   FATAL ERROR at Worklight Initialization:  the service is currently not
>   available. status code from server:-1
>   [https://www.app.com:443/app/apps/services/api/app-name/iphone/init]
>   Host is not responsive.

Comment: I'm getting these too.. still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the default global timeout value is 30 seconds for all requests originating from the JavaScript framework. It is governed by the `timeout` option in common\js\initOptions.js (if you do not see it, add it and provide a different value): http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23init

Instead of changing the global timeout value, you can also change specifically `WL.Client.connect`'s timeout value by adding a `timeout` parameter to the options object you are using: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23init

```
WL.Client.connect({
    timeout: value-in-seconds,
    onSuccess: mySuccessCallback,
    onFailure: myFailureCallback
});
```

As for the "Why" - who knows. You could use some network sniffer to see what is happening in your network to see where the potential bottlenecks are, as well as compare the timestamps from the network sniffer to the timestamps in the server logs while running in trace mode to further the investigation.

Comment: What is the difference between the error REQUEST_TIMEOUT and UNRESPONSIVE_HOST

Comment: I would assume that the former means the request reached its destination but did not return by the specified/default timeout of the request, and the latter means that the destination was not reachable...?

Comment: Another thing we are going to look at, including the timeout is the maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode on the adapter.  It is currently set to the 2, the default.  If at 2, I wonder if we the system won't accept any more concurrent requests on that adapter?  Hence the unresponsive-host error

Comment: That relates to adapter requests whereas you are referring to connect requests. For connect that may happen if you impose a limit via a load balancer or other server protection.

Comment: I am using adapter authentication which is tied to the init request at least when using WL.Client.connect, it calls the onAuthRequired of our authenticator adapter.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Connect request and adapter request are two different requests.

Comment: When I see a call to 'WL.Client.connect', it seems to make a call to the /init URL which then hits our Adapter authenticator, the onAuthRequired method?

Comment: It depends on the type of authentication you have implemented... if you have protection set on your environment then a challenge is encountered, which is then given to the client and I guess that you then handle it via the adapter... I don't know what your setup is like, and it doesn't matter for this question.